# PayPal Here Android Integration

Tags: android, mobile, paypal, payment-processing

I'm trying to integrate my Android POS application with PayPal Here.  I want to plug in the PayPal Here reader, swipe cards, then process them in my own Android application.  Any suggestions or links?  Are there any other solutions available?  I've integrated PayAnywhere, but it doesn't work that well and their support is poor.  I don't want to have to apply for PCI compliance.

Thanks

Brian

Comment: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK might help.

Comment: Yes, I've seen it.  But I'm still not clear if it includes the card reader component.  The ability to swipe credit cards is an essential part of the project.

Comment: You should see it again,  you can use the camera to do card reading.

Comment: Thanks, but how does this work?  If I use the camera, I have to scan the card into the phone which wouldn't be secure like swiping the stripe would be.  This would mean I'd have to apply for PCI compliance, right?

Comment: I have spoken with people at Paypal more than once about this issue. THEY SAY they are going to release the SDK for Here on IOS first in 2014 and later on Android too. Something must be holding them back as the ability for developers to use paypals swiper in their own apps without having to open another app would do great harm to rival Square as Square status with developers is non existent. This is also keeping developers from creating apps that can compete and replace traditional pos systems used by restaurants and merchants all over the world.

Answer (score 2):

PayPal has not opened up the reader and actual credit card processing in their API's.  The Here API consists only of check-in and pay...not swiping.

Your only option is to get a 3rd party reader that comes with an SDK and then process the cards using Payments Pro or the new REST API.  This would indeed require all the PCI compliance stuff, though, which is extremely expensive.

I'm an official PayPal Partner and the developer of [USBSwiper](http://www.usbswiper.com), a POS solution that works with PayPal Pro.  I've been working with them for a long time now trying to get access to their reader SDK and the ability to process cards within my own app.  They're open to it, but there's just so much politics involved that it's very tough to actually get it done.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  This is helpful.  Looks like your solution just works on Windows and Mac.  I'm looking for a swiping solution for Android that doesn't require PCI compliance.  The only thing I've found is the PayAnywhere SDK.  I've integrated that, but their swiper doesn't work that well and support is virtually nonexistent.  Are you aware of any other Android solution?

Comment: None that wouldn't require you to go through PCI compliance, no.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal Here SDKs for iOS and Android are now available on the PayPal Developer site:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/pph-sdk-overview/

There is also a version for Windows 8.1+ in Beta, available upon request. You can email DL-PayPal-Here-SDK@ebay.com for help with any of these.